# Laravel keeps setting value for updated_at column even though I have set timestamps to false

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a model with `public $timestamps = false`. When I call `$model->save()`, a value is added to the `updated_at` column in my database even though I do not set `update_at` to a value anywhere in my code before calling `save()`.

The default value of the `updated_at` column in my database is `NULL`. The value it is set to after is the current time on my server (the same time that I get if I called `date` at the terminal/CLI). The expected behaviour is that `updated_at` is simply set to `NULL` unless I explicitly set `$model->updated_at`.

I am using Apache 2.4.7 (Ubuntu), PHP 5.5.9, MySQL 5.5.35, and Laravel 4.1.30.

Comment: Post the code of your model?

Comment: Are you sure it is Laravel making the change? Perhaps your database schema has it set to automatically update the column itself on every change?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found my problem (derp). I did have my database automatically set the updated_at column to the current date but I disabled that (and made the default value null) so that was not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that after calling the `save()` method, I called the `touch()` method on the same model which updated the timestamps. I removed the `touch()` statement. And to give myself full control over the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns, I also disabled date mutations by adding the following code to the model class:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return array();
}
```